# Hangfire not running tasks although they are in database

Tags: c#, hangfire

I'm not sure what's going on with Hangfire but calling BackgroundJob.Enqueue() adds a job to the database as "Scheduled" but nothing seems to happen. The method code does not seem to run. In the debugger no break points get hit and in my logs from inside job nothing gets printed.

```
 JobStorage.Current = new SqlServerStorage("DefaultConnection");
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I had a similar issue. In my case the problem was that my dependency injection wasn't properly wired up.

Only after I went to `Hangfire Dashboard -> Scheduled Jobs` and clicked on my job to see more details, I could see the exact exception messages i.e. "Couldn't create interface 'some_interface'".

Check if your jobs are initialised properly and that there are no errors in the 'Scheduled' part of Hangfire Dashboard.

Comment: What were you using for DI? We're running into the same problem w/ StructureMap and wondering how you went about fixing it.

Comment: I was using Ninject. I never solved the underlying problem, but slightly changed the structure of my application. I now use hangfire to call jobs within WCF service where I've got my DI wired up.

Comment: This helped me find my issue as well, which was a database error (string would be truncated).   Not really sure why the job wouldnt go into the 'failed' bucket.

Comment: It's probably because by default Hangfire re-shedules the jobs to be executed again. Only after they fail certain number of times (10, I think), they move to failed bucket.

Answer (score 0):

Good day to you.
It may possible that the Hangfire server is not running due to that schedule recurring job may not running

To setup the server, please follow the following steps:

To setup the Hangfire server you need to implement `HangfireBootstrapper` class by implementing the `IRegisteredObject` interface

After the implementation of the class you need to start and stop the Hangfire server in global.asax or startup file in the application.

For a more detailed implementation please refer this [link](http://docs.hangfire.io/en/latest/deployment-to-production/making-aspnet-app-always-running.html)

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference. See [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/94027/285661) for instructions how to write *better* "link-based" answers. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks Thom, you did wonderful editing, your editing is appreciated